# SpringMVC Request method 'GET' not supported?

Tags: spring-mvc

It is a very simple code, that I am working on to get started with Spring MVC, I have tried every option to solve this problem, but I couldn't make it. The Code runs fine to display the index.jsp(which tells me that both DispatcherServlet and the ViewResolver are working fine), but when I click the "LoginForm" to display the Login Form (loginform.jsp) so that the user can submit username and password I am getting the following exception.

```
       Here is what I am getting when I run my code

    "Sep 02, 2014 2:56:49 PM   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver handleHttpRequestMethodNotSupported
    WARNING: Request method 'GET' not supported"
```

I really appreciate any help.

**Here are some parts of my code**

**Here is my Controller**

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginForm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showForm(Map model) {
                LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
                model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
                return "/login/loginform";
        }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringMvc</display-name>
  <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>firstMvc</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
         org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:spring/firstMvc-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>firstMvc</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3, MVC Examples</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Spring 3, MVC Examples</h1>
    <ul>
        <li style="width: 130px;"><a href="<spring:url value="/loginform.html"     htmlEscape="true" />"> Login Form</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**loginform.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring3Example</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h3>Login Form</h3>
    <FONT color="blue">

        <h6>User Name="UserName" and password="password"</h6>

    </FONT>
    <form:form action="loginform.html" commandName="loginForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                            path="userName" /></FONT></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                            path="password" /></FONT></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </form:form>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In spring you don't have to *.html. Just use controller value. And in views.xml you have to set your value to jsp file.

```
<form:form action="/loginform" commandName="loginForm">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User Name:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                            path="userName" /></FONT></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:<FONT color="red"><form:errors
                            path="password" /></FONT></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:password path="password" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
      </form:form>
```